# MAC Address Filtering in IPTABLES

Tags: centos, iptables

I am new to CentOS7 and currently working on a project which requires very limited amount of users to access the Cent OS 7 Server via SSH so using the IPtables command to provide access to only certain users.

Below is the command i am using to allow access to one user with a mac address:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT
```

it works and is added in the iptables as per below output:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh MAC XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

When adding the 2nd rule to block all others from accessing port 22, i get disconnected from the Cent OS 7 box:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP
```

Any ideas where i could be going wrong

Answer (score 1):

What is 'going wrong' is that you are telling iptables in the second command: drop all connections on destination port 22, and that apparently includes your own connection to the box. Are you connecting from the client computer with the MAC address specified in the first rule?

I would recommend you go about this using an iptables rules file. And use the commands `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`. Basically you create a text file (`iptables_rulesv4`) and then tell iptables to restore itself from this rules. Here is a basic example with two rules.

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -m comment --comment "Allow ssh connections from specific MAC address" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Maintain open connections" -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

1: `*filter` - This is the iptables table to manipulate, the filter table

2-4: These files are the default state: INPUT and FORWARD are dropped (DROP) by default, OUTPUT is allowed (ACCEPT) be default.

5: Rule 1 - Allows port ssh connections that originate from MAC address `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`.

6: Rule 2 - Allow all established or open connections.

7: Commit these rules to iptables.

Note: iptables works by matching the packet with the first rule it finds that matches, and then if no rules match, it uses the corresponding default rule.

You can then run command

```
sudo iptables-restore iptables_rulesv4
```

To apply these rules to the computer. Then you can view your ruleset with

```
sudo iptables -L -n -t filter
```

Please note: Do not blindly use the above ruleset for your server. It is only intended as an example. You must determine what your security needs are and what you is secure for your organization, and design a ruleset that meets your security needs.

Comment: thanks for the response. We want to only allow a set of computers. Yes i am connecting to the box from the computer which is specified in the first rule. Is there any documentation or link which can guide me on iptables rules file. Thanks alot

Comment: Google search ["Centos 7 iptables tutorial"](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=ZLFXX5TNMLCclwTE2oPYDA&q=centos+7+iptables+tutorial&oq=centos+7+iptables+tutorial&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAA6BQgAELEDOggIABCxAxCDAToGCAAQFhAeOggIIRAWEB0QHlDFBFidNGDVNGgBcAB4AIABqAGIAb8kkgEEMC4zMJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiUj8G0_dnrAhUwzoUKHUTtAMsQ4dUDCAk&uact=5) and you should find multiple websites about itpables.